# How to rotate svg circle

Tags: svg

I want to use the same svg, but instead want the half circle svg to be rotated 90 degrees. How do I do this? Thanks.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### SVG syntax

- must not use units in the `rotate()` function
- can state the rotation center only as part of the attribute

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" transform="rotate(90, 50 50)" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

#### CSS syntax

- must use units for `rotate()` function and transform origin
- can state the rotation center only as CSS `transform-origin`

```css
path {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

To *use the same SVG* (which is what is desired and differentiates this answer from other answers) you can reference the original SVG from a `<use>` element in a new SVG and apply a CSS rotation.

```css
.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" />
  <path d="M0,50 a1,1 0 0,0 100,0" fill="orange" />
</svg>

<svg class="rotate90" width="100" height="100">
  <use href="#mySVG"/>
</svg>
```